# OIDC authentication in springdoc-openapi-ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc

I'm migrating from the springfox project.

How should I configure springdoc to enable popup where user can type username and password to authenticate in Keycloak using password flow? With the following setup I have no available authorizations in the list when pressing `Authorize` button

[image]

#### pom.xml

```java
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
...
```

#### OpenApiConfig.java

```java
@Bean    
public OpenAPI api() {
  return new OpenAPI()
          ...
          .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("OAuth"))
          .components(
            new Components()
              .addSecuritySchemes("OAuth",
                new SecurityScheme()
                  .name("OAuth")
                  .type(SecurityScheme.Type.OPENIDCONNECT)
                  .scheme("bearer")
            )
        );
}
```

#### application.yaml

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    oauth:
      use-pkce-with-authorization-code-grant: true
      client-id: my-client
      clent-secret: my-client-secret
      realm: my-realm
      app-name: app-name
      oauth2RedirectUrl: https://keycloak.service.example.org
```

Comment: For me, the missing part in similar situation was this annotation on the Controller: `@SecurityRequirement(name = "OAuth")`